# Context menu for textinput react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, whatsapp

Can I change the android context menu that pops up after long taping the text input  using react native, or natively (both on ios and android) if react native can not do that? What I'am trying to do is give user options to alter the text like in whatsapp:

[whatsapp context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDBZY.png)

It is also possible to insert markers at the ends of highlighted text. How can I obtain similar results?